# EF Queries Getting Executed Twice

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

```
[Test]
    public void GetSomeData()
     {
         myEntities _context = new myEntities();
         var result = from c in _context.Categories.Select(c => c.ParentCategoryID == null)
                      select c;
         var list = result.ToList();
     }
```

When looking in profiler I see this getting executed twice. Why is this and how do I prevent this from happening.

Comment: are you sure? could it be the start and end of the statement?

Comment: Positive, I am looking at it in Sql profiler

Comment: No queries get executed until result.ToList() is called, once I go .ToList() i see it executed twice.

Comment: batch start and batch complete are there twice, so a total of for entries in the profiler window for my test. However when I user

Comment: I would try downloading a free trial of EF Prof (http://efprof.com/) just to make sure the query is running twice. Also try this : var list = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryID == null).ToList();